# In Xamarin Android Edittext, how to apply different color for border and background

Tags: xamarin.android, android-edittext, border, background-color

I prepared a simple sample using the edittext control and applied border color(bottom line) using the Background Property. But if I apply the background color using the SetBackgroundColor method, the border color is also changed. So I need to know how to apply different color for border and background for edit text in Xamarin Android.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying both colors separately. You can **create an xml and with solid and stroke (background/fill & border) for the shape of edittext** in drawable folder and set that xml to the background property of the edittext

**editText_Bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid
      android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>  
  <stroke
      android:color="#238999"
      android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

**In Layout file,** Set this to the background property of EditText

```
  <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:background="@drawable/editText_Bg"
            android:text="Welcome"/>
```

(or)
**In Activity.cs,** you can use `SetBackgroundResource`

```
var editTxt = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);            
editTxt.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.editText_Bg);
```

In codebehind **Programatically** /**Dynamic update** of colors, No need to create editText_bg.xml

```
 var editTxt = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
 GradientDrawable BgColor = new GradientDrawable();
 BgColor.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
 BgColor.SetColor(Color.Rgb(0,255,0)); //Background Color
 BgColor.SetStroke(1, Color.Rgb(255,0,0));//Border Color
 editTxt.Background = BgColor;
```

Comment: How to access the editText_Bg.xml resource using C# code?

Comment: I have edited my answer, Please check

Comment: If I dynamically change the background color using SetBackgroundColor method the border is also changed which doesn't meet my requirement.

Comment: Please edit your query appropriately, so that it would be clear to understand. If you are looking for dynamic update, then you wont need editText_Bg.xml. Because values in resource files are static.

Comment: Edited my answer for dynamic update of background/border colors

Comment: I have tried using SetBackgroundResource in the Activity .cs and it showed that there was no problems. And I correct the small error in the answer above, which should be changed to: editTxt.Background = BgColor;